# Unable to set Boolean quantities in drools workbench 6.4.0

Tags: drools

I made a simple guided rule, to set the student eligible = True when their gpa > 2. But every time I validate the project, an error pops up saying: `The method setEligible(Boolean) in the type Student is not applicable for the arguments (boolean).`

I followed the [blog post](http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/bpm/jbpm/get-started-with-jbpm-kie-and-drools-workbench-part-3) to make a guided rule.

Comment: provide the rule....

Comment: Link to the rule I applied: [image](http://i0.wp.com/www.adeveloperdiary.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Get-started-with-jBPM-KIE-Drools-Workbench-adeveloperdiary.com-24.jpg?w=620)

Comment: What I can see, the only difference is native datatype `Boolean ` and `boolean `

Comment: @piyushj what is the workaround for the same?

Comment: Can you show your pojo for the same?